# Gmail and hotmail are tagging my mails as spam?

Tags: exchange-2010

We have two domains .local and .com. Sending connector uses .com fqdn while receiving connector uses .local fdn. I got an error "no reverse dns set". So i called my isp and get it done. After doing it.Gmail and hotmail started tagging my mails as spam.
While testing on mxtools i got smtp mismatch error.

I have
One send connector
Two receive connector- default and client.
Not able to change fqdn on default.
Server authentication is not letting me do so. We have Microsoft front page security for exchange. We are using firewall in which exchange ip is mapped to public ip.(nat).

Comment: Without more information it is hard to say but it sounds like your MX records may not match your configuration.  Again, we would need more detailed information regarding your issue.

Comment: since setting rdns broke this, i'm going to guess that your new rdns record has a non-matching forward pointer.  There must be matching records; RDNS & A record / fwd pointer or this can happen.

Comment: we have two primary dns:-(1) example.com (2)example.local.  In example.com we have A record as mail ip address is 192.168.1.11 which is our exchange server ip. Than this ip is mapped with external public ip in our firewall.

Answer (score 1):

your PTR should be the same as your mail server name. (The name it uses when you telnet to your smtp server). Also a valid PTR needs an A record, too.

Bests,
Semir